# error test routing with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, tdd

I have this resource in my `config/routes.rb`

```
resources :users, :path => "u" do
 resources :boards, :controller => 'users/boards', :path => "collections"
end
```

In my `spec/routing/boards_routing_spec.rb` i have:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Users::BoardsController do
  describe "routing" do

    it "routes to #index" do
      get("/u/:user_id/collections").should route_to("users/boards#index")
    end

  end
end
```

I get the next error:

```
Failures:

  1) Users::BoardsController routing routes to #index
     Failure/Error: get("/u/:user_id/collections").should route_to("users/boards#index")
       The recognized options <{"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"users/boards", "user_id"=>":user_id"}> did not match <{"controller"=>"users/boards", "action"=>"index"}>, difference: <{"user_id"=>":user_id"}>.
       <{"controller"=>"users/boards", "action"=>"index"}> expected but was
       <{"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"users/boards", "user_id"=>":user_id"}>.
     # ./spec/routing/boards_routing_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I am using Devise 2.0 for user.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was fixed:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Users::BoardsController do
  describe "routing" do

    it "routes to #index" do
      get("/u/hyperrjas/collections").should route_to("users/boards#index", :user_id => "hyperrjas")
    end
end
```